# NSData bytes not matching bytes from Java WS with same base64 string

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, web-services

I am using protocol buffers in an iOS application. The app consumes a web service written in Java, which spits back a base64 encoded string.

The base64 string is the *same* on both ends.

In the app however, whenever I try to convert the string to NSData, the number of bytes may or may not be the same on both ends. The result is a possible invalid protocol buffer exception, invalid end tag.

For example:

```
Source(bytes) | NSData  | Diff
93              93         0
6739            6735      -4
5745            5739      -6
```

The bytes are equal in the trivial case of an empty protocol buffer.

Here is the Java source:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

....

public static String bytesToBase64(byte[] bytes) {
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
}
```

On the iOS side, I have tried various algorithms from similar questions which all agree in byte size and content.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What does your iOS code look like? And what does the base64 look like? Also, I've in the past run into issues with some base64 decoders not expecting newlines to be in the source - not sure if that applies here but something to look at.

Comment: You should compare the source (before encoding) and destination (after decoding) bytes to see if bytes are being omitted in the middle somewhere or on the  end.  There are some niggling details about padding the end of the string that may be fouling you up.

Answer (score 0):

On closer inspection, the issue was my assumption that Base64 is Base64. I was using the **url** variant in the web service while the app's decode was expecting a normal version.

I noticed underscores in the Base64, which I thought odd.

The Base64 page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 map of value/char shows no underscores, but later in the article goes over variants, which do use underscores.